# Simple .txt File-Reading with ifstream

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

Just what is probably a basic question for something I haven't been able to figure out all day. Here's a snippet of code in C++:

```
Escape::Escape(std::string filename)
{
   std::ifstream file;
   file.open(filename.c_str());
   if (file.is_open()) {
      file >> gridWidth >> gridHeight >> nKeys;
      std::cout << "gridWidth = " << gridWidth << std::endl;
      std::cout << "gridHeight = " << gridHeight << std::endl;
      std::cout << "nKeys = " << nKeys << std::endl;
      /* irrelevant code below */
```

Basically I want this code to read the first three integers of a text file and save them into the variables gridWidth, gridHeight, and nKeys. These are private integers of a class called "Escape". Here are the first few lines of the text file:

```
8
8
1
BUL--/EUR--/BUL--/BU---/BU---/BU---/BU---/BUR--/
(more text below)
```

And here is some sample output of this code:

```
gridWidth = 107764358
gridHeight = -991553646
nKeys = 0
```

On running this code multiple times, `gridWidth` and `gridHeight` are always junk and nKeys is always 0. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT: The problem was with the filename I passed to `file.open()`. I passed in the relative filename which, although openable, was not linkable to the ifstream. The problem was resolved by using the text file's absolute filename instead.**

Comment: test the file by piping it to `cout` really quick

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `file >> gridWidth >> gridHeight >> nKeys;` do this instead:

`while(file >> gridWidth && file >> gridHeight && file >> nKeys)`

This would be better than storing the results in a string and then having to do a conversion.

Comment: I tried this too with the same old results. gridWidth is junk, gridHeight is junk, and nKeys is 0. I admit that this is much better style though and this is the solution I will try to incorporate. Is it possible that there is some other reason for these errors? Thanks

Comment: @BanjoKaJoey I have made an example text file and edited my answer, I think it's due to your loop `while(file.is_open())`

Comment: @billz yeah that's definitely his issue then, I seemed to have read the `if` as a `while` since it's expected.